# Is it possible to see real images without a screen?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, refraction

I have always wondered about this question, so searched it up on the internet and there were contrasting ideas.Some said that it can be seen but the others said it can't.

According to me we are able to see everyday objects due to formation real images, the retina acts as a screen for the formation.

Comment: what do you mean by a screen?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the optical system of your eyes projects real images on your retina. But the real images a lens outside your eyes projects on a screen, you can only see if you put your ey, so the rays making the image meet it, so you have to position it at one very specific place